# Use argument 2 until @ for loop

Tags: bash

I have a shell skript:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec_command -k -q $1

for i in $@
do
  grep --color=always "$i" file
done
```

I call the script as

```
./grepskript -v searchstring1 searchstring2
```

I want to use the first argument for the `exec_command` and all other arguments for the `do` loop. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you edit your question? as is, you say `./grepskript -v searchstring1 searchstring2` : it seems grepskript is the name of the script itself, and that you intend in it to execute $1 (which is "-v" ?? is it really the executable name you want to execute?) and then do a loop grepping for "searchstring1" in the file, and then grepping "searchstring2" in the file, separately?

Comment: @OlivierDulac the name of the script is `grepskript`. It does a calculation `exec_command` (with option -v). which outputs a file `file` from which I then `grep` seperately `saerchstring1` and then `searchstring2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `shift` command to push the positional arguments as you need. In your case, doing `shift 1` would separate `$1` (i.e. the first argument) from the rest of the args. Similarly `shift 2` would shift first 2 arguments from the argument list and so on. And always remember to quote your variables/arguments to *not* let undergo word-splitting by the shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec_command -k -q "$1"
shift 1

for i in "$@"; do
  grep --color=always "$i" file
done
```

See the [`shift`](https://ss64.com/bash/shift.html) man page to understand more.  This is a POSIX compliant option available across shells.

Or another way to do (`bash` specific) an index based expansion on the argument list `$@` as below to start the loop from 2nd element on wards.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec_command -k -q "$1"

for i in "${@:2}"; do
  grep --color=always -- "$i" file
done
```

Also while iterating over the positional arguments in the first approach, you do just

```
for i; do
  grep --color=always -- "$i" file
done
```